# Error with "uses" in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Hi I have a problem with the following code, the problem is that I seem to forget a component when using "use" because it always gives me the error "tagBITMAP", the code is as follows:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,Vcl.Graphics,Vcl.Imaging.jpeg,Windows;



procedure capturar_pantalla(nombre: string);

// Function capturar() based in :
// http://forum.codecall.net/topic/60613-how-to-capture-screen-with-delphi-code/
// http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2001/a/bltip0501_4.htm
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971605/show-mouse-cursor-in-screenshot-with-delphi
// Thanks to Zarko Gajic , Luthfi and Ken White

var
  aca: HDC;
  tan: TRect;
  posnow: TPoint;
  imagen1: TBitmap;
  imagen2: TJpegImage;
  curnow: THandle;

begin

  aca := GetWindowDC(GetDesktopWindow);
  imagen1 := TBitmap.Create;

  GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow, tan);
  imagen1.Width := tan.Right - tan.Left;
  imagen1.Height := tan.Bottom - tan.Top;
  BitBlt(imagen1.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, imagen1.Width, imagen1.Height, aca, 0,
    0, SRCCOPY);

  GetCursorPos(posnow);

  curnow := GetCursor;
  DrawIconEx(imagen1.Canvas.Handle, posnow.X, posnow.Y, curnow, 32, 32, 0, 0,
    DI_NORMAL);

  imagen2 := TJpegImage.Create;
  imagen2.Assign(imagen1);
  imagen2.CompressionQuality := 60;
  imagen2.SaveToFile(nombre);

  imagen1.Free;
  imagen2.Free;

end;

//



begin
  try
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: FWIW, when you have a compiler error, you should report it verbatim

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue here is one of scope. Both the `Windows` unit and the `Graphics` unit define a type named `TBitmap`. The compiler can see both types and the scoping rules are that the last defined is the one the the compiler uses.

Since the `Windows` unit is introduced after `Graphics`, your code is finding the `TBitmap` defined in the `Windows` unit. But you want the one defined in the `Graphics` unit.

Solve the problem by moving `Windows` to appear before `Graphics` in the uses clause.

Now, alternatively you could leave the uses clause alone and fully specify the type: `Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap`. I think you'll agree that re-ordering the uses clause is preferable.

As an aside, I don't think very much of this code. It completely neglects to check the Win32 API return values for errors. I suggest that once you can make it compile, you add error checking. The function `Win32Check` from `SysUtils` is your friend. And some try/finally to protect the bitmaps' lifetime is also needed.

Comment: Funny, I would go for the explicit Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap. That way my code informs me that there is a potential conflict to watch out for in this unit. What if the uses clause ever gets reordered?

Comment: @Jan If the clause is reordered then the code fails to compile. So there's no danger. It's no fun writing `Bitmap := Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap.Create;`

Comment: @Jan As a general rule, I take care to use a consistent ordering policy in my code. Lower level units first. So, system units, then RTL, then VCL, then 3rd party components, then my low level units, then my business logic, then UI. You get the idea.

Comment: I do the same, that's why my units sometimes 'get reordered' ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the help David Heffernan

Comment: yes, but I resolved this morning already,