# How capture only the region of mouse click on screen?

Tags: delphi, winapi, screenshot, mouse-coordinates

The code following makes a screenshot of desktop every time that mouse left button is clicked.
But i'm wanting make a screenshot only of region where happens mouse click, for example if some button is clicked on some website, the screenshot must be only of this button.

[image]

*GIF*

[image]

This is possible?

if yes, i will very happy if someone show a code example! Thanks in advance.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  Windows,
  Messages,
  SysUtils,
  Graphics,
  Imaging.PngImage;
  
type
  MouseLLHookStruct = record
  end;
  
const
  WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;
  
var
  Msg: TMsg;
  mHook: Cardinal;

procedure GetCursor(ScreenShotBitmap: TBitmap);
var
  R: TRect;
  Icon: TIcon;
  II: TIconInfo;
  CI: TCursorInfo;
begin
  R := ScreenShotBitmap.Canvas.ClipRect;
  Icon := TIcon.Create;
  try
    CI.cbSize := SizeOf(CI);
    if GetCursorInfo(CI) then
      if CI.Flags = CURSOR_SHOWING then
      begin
        Icon.Handle := CopyIcon(CI.hCursor);
        if GetIconInfo(Icon.Handle, II) then
        begin
          ScreenShotBitmap.Canvas.Draw(CI.ptScreenPos.X - Integer(II.xHotspot) -
            R.Left, CI.ptScreenPos.Y - Integer(II.yHotspot) - R.Top, Icon);
        end;
      end;
  finally
    Icon.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure ScreenCapture;
var
  DC: HDC;
  Rect: TRect;
  png: TPngImage;
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
begin
  png := TPngImage.Create;
  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow, Rect);
  DC := GetWindowDC(GetDesktopWindow);
  try
    Bitmap.Width := Rect.Right - Rect.Left;
    Bitmap.Height := Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top;
    BitBlt(Bitmap.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Bitmap.Width, Bitmap.Height, DC, 0,
      0, SRCCOPY);
    GetCursor(Bitmap);
    png.Assign(Bitmap);
    png.SaveToFile('screenshot.png');
  finally
    ReleaseDC(GetDesktopWindow, DC);
    png.Free;
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;

function LowLevelMouseHookProc(nCode: LongInt; WPARAM: WPARAM; lParam: lParam)
  : LRESULT; stdcall;
var
  info: ^MouseLLHookStruct absolute lParam;
begin
  Result := CallNextHookEx(mHook, nCode, WPARAM, lParam);
  if (WPARAM = WM_LBUTTONUP) then
    ScreenCapture;
end;

begin
  mHook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, @LowLevelMouseHookProc, HInstance, 0);
  
  while GetMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0) do
  begin
    TranslateMessage(Msg);
    DispatchMessage(Msg);
  end;
  UnhookWindowsHookEx(mHook);

end.
```

---

**EDIT:**

I found a alternative in VB.NET. But how could be a solution with Delphi code?

```
Private Shared Function CaptureCursor(ByRef x As Integer, ByRef y As Integer) As Bitmap
        Dim bmp As Bitmap
        Dim hicon As IntPtr
        Dim ci As New CURSORINFO()
        Dim icInfo As ICONINFO
        ci.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(ci)
        If GetCursorInfo(ci) Then
            hicon = CopyIcon(ci.hCursor)
            If GetIconInfo(hicon, icInfo) Then
                x = ci.ptScreenPos.X - CInt(icInfo.xHotspot)
                y = ci.ptScreenPos.Y - CInt(icInfo.yHotspot)
                Dim ic As Icon = Icon.FromHandle(hicon)
                bmp = ic.ToBitmap()
                ic.Dispose()
                Return bmp
            End If
        End If
        Return Nothing
    End Function

'Insert on Timer tick event
    Private Sub Screenshot()
        Dim x As Integer
        Dim y As Integer

        Dim cursorBmp As Bitmap = CaptureCursor(x, y)

        Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Cursor.Size.Width, Cursor.Size.Height)
        Dim sourceLocation As Point = Control.MousePosition

        sourceLocation.Offset(-16, -16)

        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
            g.CopyFromScreen(sourceLocation, Point.Empty, bmp.Size)
            g.DrawImage(cursorBmp, x - sourceLocation.X, y - sourceLocation.Y)
            cursorBmp.Dispose()
        End Using

        Me.PictureBox1.Image = bmp
    End Sub
```

Comment: [BitBlt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-bitblt).

Comment: Do you need the effect that GIF shows?

Comment: `the screenshot must be only of this button.`  If you just click on a corner of a button, such as the lower right corner of the button. How to display the screenshot? I don't know how to get instances of buttons on a web page, but I think it has something to do with CSS. If you need to click a certain part of the button to display the whole screen capture of the button, I don't think it's a simple thing. At least you need to be familiar with the layout and properties of the controls on the web page.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT, *`Do you need the effect that GIF shows?`* - Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way, you can refer to the code in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971605/show-mouse-cursor-in-screenshot-with-delphi),

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Windows, Graphics;

procedure DrawCursor (ACanvas:TCanvas; Position:TPoint) ;
var
  HCursor : THandle;
begin
  HCursor := GetCursor;
  DrawIconEx(ACanvas.Handle, Position.X, Position.Y,
              HCursor, 32, 32, 0, 0, DI_NORMAL) ;
end;

function CaptureWindow(const WindowHandle: HWnd): TBitmap;
var
  DC: HDC;
  wRect: TRect;
  CurPos: TPoint;
begin
  DC := GetWindowDC(WindowHandle);
  Result := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    GetWindowRect(WindowHandle, wRect);
    Result.Width := wRect.Right - wRect.Left;
    Result.Height := wRect.Bottom - wRect.Top;
    BitBlt(Result.Canvas.Handle, 
           0, 
           0, 
           Result.Width, 
           Result.Height, 
           DC, 
           0, 
           0, 
           SRCCOPY);
    GetCursorPos(CurPos);
    DrawCursor(Result.Canvas, CurPos);
  finally
    ReleaseDC(WindowHandle, DC);
  end;
end;

// Sample usage starts here
var
  Bmp: TBitmap;

begin
  Bmp := CaptureWindow(GetDesktopWindow);
  Bmp.SaveToFile('D:\TempFiles\FullScreenCap.bmp');
  Bmp.Free;
  WriteLn('Screen captured.');
  ReadLn;
end.
```

This code can get the screen capture containing the mouse position, just use `BitBlt` to specify the mouse coordinates and rectangle size (button size), and finally get the BMP image you need. Use `DrawImage` to draw the BMP image into a rectangular box, as shown in GIF.

Mouse coordinates can be obtained by calling `GetCursorInfo`, and the size of the rectangle can be specified according to your needs.

Note that after you have the mouse coordinates, you need to subtract the size of half a rectangle to the left and up respectively when you pass them into `BitBlt`.

For example,

```
BitBlt(Newhdc, 
           0, 
           0, 
           rect_x,  //size of the rect 
           rect_y, 
           HDC, 
           x - half_rect_x,  //x,y => mouse coordinates
           y - half_rect_y,  //half_rect_x, half_rect_y  => the size of half the rectangle
           SRCCOPY);
```